# How to display Django model's foreign key as its attribute in admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django Admin, my model CNAME has a foreign key to AuthUser, when I create a model instance, I must choose a User, but there display the AuthUser's Object number,

how to display username in there?

[image]

---

The model details:

```
class CNAME(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, help_text=". eg:gat.google.com")
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=5120, null=True, blank=True, help_text="desc")

    desc_en = models.CharField(max_length=5120, null=True, blank=True, help_text="desc）")

    user = models.OneToOneField(unique=True, to=AuthUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, help_text="belong to user")

    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "CNAME"
        verbose_name_plural = "CNAME"

class AuthUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.IntegerField()
    is_active = models.IntegerField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

In my admin.py I register it:

```
admin.site.register(CNAME)


class CNAMEAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'desc', 'desc_en',  'user', 'ctime', 'uptime']
    list_filter = []
    search_fields = ['name', 'desc']
    list_per_page = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `__str__` method in your AuthUser model:

```
class AuthUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.IntegerField()
    is_active = models.IntegerField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```